# Symfony build form text fields with data from array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, symfony

In Symfony I need to create a form with text fields that would hold data pulled from the database for editing. At the moment I have this code where I am getting a question with it's four answers:

```
$question = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('QuizBundle:Question')->findOneByIdJoinedToCategory($id);
$data = $question->getAnswers();
```

This retrives the question and the answers which are stored in an Array Collection.
At the moment I can build the form with the question data, but how can I use the answers from the Array Collection to build text fields with the data? 
I can also convert the array collection to a regular array, if so how to build text fields with data from a regular array? 
Thanks

**Form Builder:**

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($question)
            ->add('Image', TextType::class)
            ->add('Question', TextType::class)
            ->add('answers', TextType::class,
                   array('data' => array()))
            ->add('Submit',SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Edit Record'))
        ->getForm();
```

[image]

Comment: did you check [EntityType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)  ?

Comment: @Glasset Tried it now. Using entity type I get all the answers from the table. I only need the answers for the specific question. Using the posted code I manage to get the question and the answers in the array collection( my entities are related oneToMany) but I don't know how to have text fields containing the answers value when building the form.

Comment: you have to pass through the '$options' the array from controller... this is one way, but there is another way to do it, but I don't remember right now

Comment: @V.Sambor I am just building the form in the controller at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this page from symfony documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html
**CollectionType Field** is what you are looking.

Comment: Something like this: 
`->add('answers', CollectionType::class, array(
                 'entry_type'   => TextType::class,
                 'entry_options'  => array(
                    'attr'      => array('class' => 'email-box')
                ),
            ))`

Comment: glad it helps :) All the best!

Comment: I can't get it working, as you can see I am quite new to Symfony and this form building is giving me headache. From my post to create the textfield from the collection, do I need to pass $question, or $data? And where do I pass it in the add statement?